# Bash text multi line into one line with spec. data

Tags: linux, bash, tex

I got something like this

```
Title  : Magic Moments                   Artist: Perry Como
Album  : Original American Songbook: 50  Year: 2005, Genre: Other (12)
Comment: DrBN                            Track: 7
```

And I need this

```
Magic Moments,Perry Como,Original American Songbook: 50,2005,Other (12),DrBN,7
```

I am new with the bash and I dont know how can I get this
Thanks for you help!

EDIT

```
Title  : Magic Moments                   Artist: Perry Como                    
Album  : Original American Songbook: 50  Year: 2005, Genre: Other (12)
Comment: DrBN                            Track: 7
Title  : Stormy Weather                  Artist: Frank Sinatra                 
Album  : Original American Songbook: 50  Year: 2005, Genre: Other (12)
Comment: DrBN                            Track: 8
Title  : Let There Be Love               Artist: Sammy Davis, Jr.              
Album  : Original American Songbook: 50  Year: 2005, Genre: Other (12)
Comment: DrBN                            Track: 9
Title  : Makin' Whoopee                  Artist: Esther Williams               
Album  : Original American Songbook: 50  Year: 2005, Genre: Other (12)
Comment: DrBN                            Track: 10
Title  : Spanish Eyes                    Artist: Al Martino                    
Album  : Original American Songbook: 50  Year: 2005, Genre: Other (12)
Comment: DrBN                            Track: 11
Title  : 'S Wonderful {From An American  Artist: Gene Kelly; Georges Guétary   
Album  : Original American Songbook: 50  Year: 2005, Genre: Other (12)
Comment: DrBN                            Track: 12
Title  : Out Of My Head                  Artist: John Newman                   
Album  : Tribute (Deluxe Edition)        Year: 2013, Genre: Pop (13)
Comment: no coment                       Track: 6
```

Comment: I suppose, word `Songbook` should be skipped as column name

Comment: did you make sufficient research into solving this before posting it here?

Comment: RomanPerekhrest no this is the data from the file, it can not be skipped
Inian yes I have read about the text transformation, but this example seems a little bit too difficult for me for now.
I know what should I do but I do not know how.
1)erase the space between 'columns'  
2)erase the new line sign
3)and maybe get the value past by :

Comment: could be there other lines except those three?

Comment: Yes it will be a whole file with that kind of data

Comment: @Eken, you said *it can not be skipped* - so, what else can not be skipped if there would be more lines? Your logic is unclear

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest sorry, maybe this would be helpful 
Info about the file mp3, such as title, artist, year ... this is what I am interesting in, everything else is useless.
The data.txt contain info about many files mp3

Comment: can you extend your input example with more entries?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sed` and `paste`, as in

```
sed 's/Title *: //;s/ *Artist: /,/;s/Album *: //; s/ *Year: /,/;s/ *Genre: //;s/Comment: //;s/ *Track: /,/' | paste -sd,
```

Of course, if you have multiple records/albums/tracks, or if the field names may change, there are better solutions.

Comment: Thanks, it is a solid base for me, as you wrote names may change, thanks again!